# Spring data findAll() does not fetch eagerly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, eager-loading

I have two entities with unidirectional `one to many` relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Basket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private int capacity;
}

@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Basket basket;
}
```

I save couple of objects:

```
    Basket basket1 = new Basket(100);
    Basket basket2 = new Basket(200);
    Basket basket3 = new Basket(300);
    basketRepository.save(asList(basket1, basket2, basket3));

    Item item1 = new Item("item1", basket1);
    Item item11 = new Item("item11", basket1);
    Item item2 = new Item("item2", basket2);
    Item item22 = new Item("item22", basket2);
    Item item3 = new Item("item3", basket3);
    Item item33 = new Item("item33", basket3);
    itemRepository.save(asList(item1, item11, item2, item22, item3, item33));

    // Loading one item. Basket fetched eagerly.
    itemRepository.findOne(1L);

    // Loading many items. Baskets are not loaded (n+1 select problem).
    itemRepository.findAll();
```

`@ManyToOne` annotation uses `eager fetch` by default.
When I load one `Item` using `findOne()`, Hibernate generates query with `left outer join` and `Basket` is fetched in the same query.
However when I use `findAll()`, Hibernate first fetches all `Items` and then executes `N selects` (one per each `Basket`), so that it leads to `(n+1) select problem`. Why Hiberante doesn't eagerly fetch `Basket` objects with `findAll()` method and how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override findAll method with @Query annotation in your repository. Below is the sample code

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {
    @Override
    @Query("select item from Item item left join fetch item.basket")
    Iterable<Item> findAll();
}
```

Then you can log your sql queries to see that only one query is made

```
Hibernate: select item0_.id as id1_1_0_, basket1_.id as id1_0_1_, item0_.basket_id as basket_i3_1_0_, item0_.name as name2_1_0_, basket1_.capacity as capacity2_0_1_ from item item0_ left outer join basket basket1_ on item0_.basket_id=basket1_.id
```

And before it was

```
2018-03-09 13:26:52.269  INFO 4268 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select item0_.id as id1_1_, item0_.basket_id as basket_i3_1_, item0_.name as name2_1_ from item item0_
Hibernate: select basket0_.id as id1_0_0_, basket0_.capacity as capacity2_0_0_ from basket basket0_ where basket0_.id=?
Hibernate: select basket0_.id as id1_0_0_, basket0_.capacity as capacity2_0_0_ from basket basket0_ where basket0_.id=?
Hibernate: select basket0_.id as id1_0_0_, basket0_.capacity as capacity2_0_0_ from basket basket0_ where basket0_.id=?
```

Answer (score 14):

From [JPA 2.0](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) spec, @ManyToOne are by default EAGER.

Now, when you use `findAll()` it is equivalent to firing a JPQL query like `entityManager.createQuery(...)` and it by default loads the `items` first and subsequently for `each item` it loads the `basket` entity and causing N+1 problem.

You can follow one of the two approaches:

1. Override the default query used by specifying [@Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) annotation on the `findAll` method and use the query with join like `select i from Item i left join fetch i.basket`.
2. Use [@NamedEntityGraph](https://martinsdeveloperworld.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/using-namedentitygraph-to-load-jpa-entities-more-selectively-in-n1-scenarios/) with name say `basket` on `Item` class and specify which part of the `Item` graph needs to be loaded eagerly. On the `findAll` method, use `@EntityGraph(value = "basket")`. *Note that as per [spring jpa entity graph](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph), we can also use `attributePath` to define ad-hoc entity graphs via `@EntityGraph without the need of having to explicitly add @NamedEntityGraph to your domain types`.*

Comment: Or override 'findAll' method and just add `@EntityGrath(attributePaths = "basket")` Spring annotation to make the method load 'basket' eagerly.

Comment: Oh yeah..it is `@EntityGraph(value = "basket", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)`. I was trying it outside spring repo so using setHint manually on entityManger. Updating the answer.

Comment: The second param is not necessary because it's used by [default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/EntityGraph.html#type--). And `value` param is for 'named grath'. We must use `attributePaths` param here.

Comment: yeah, but default it is FETCH. Not sure if it is value or attributePath, I couldn't try with spring repo right now.

Comment: Got it now. As per https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph,  we can use `attributePath` to define ad-hoc entity graphs via `@EntityGraph` without the need of having to explicitly add `@NamedEntityGraph` to your domain types.

Comment: This answer is more specific and gives more solutions. ``@EntityGraph`` is definitly the way to go, you shouldn't use ``@Query`` to override default find implementation.